# How do you prevent friends from joining your game?

Tags: diablo-iii

When trying to get some solo achievements or when running the game for the first time with a new friend, your other friends can be a bit too friendly and barge in, killing everything or just making the mobs beefier.  How do you block people from joining your game?

Comment: There is a way to block **only** in my hardcore heroes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can prevent people on your friend list from automatically joining your games by **unchecking** the **"Allow Quick Join"** option in the Social tab in Options (in the <kbd>Esc</kbd> menu), which is set by default.

If someone attempts to join your game as usual, it will notify you and ask your permission before they can hop in.

[image: Social tab in options]

Comment: You beat me to it, but you answered it yourself? hah oh well, at least leave this up.. there will be plenty of people who will want to know how to do this once may 15th comes around. :]

Comment: Can i change my online status to offline so that my friend can't see me online? Some of my friend keep asking me to let them join my game and sometimes it is hard to keep reject them....