# Why can't I join all of my friends' Diablo III games?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I sign into Battle.net, it lists some of my online friends whose games I could join. However it doesn't list all of them. Why are some people not listed?

Comment: Relevant: [How do you prevent friends from joining your game?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63738/how-do-you-prevent-friends-from-joining-your-game)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default there is an active setting called "Allow Quick Join" for your friends to join the game.

Although, (possibly in your case) **they can turn off this option to require an invite to join the game first.**

Comment: I can provide a screen shot for this image once i get home from work.