# I'm hearing rumors of Battle.net accounts being hijacked and stolen in Diablo 3. How can I protect myself?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

There have been [a fairly large number](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5235706038?page=1) of [fairly reliable reports](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/txvx0/gathering_information_please_respond_to_this/) that [some clever and disreputable ***jerks***](http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3485990) have figured out how to hijack a Diablo III session, steal your Battle.net account, take all of your cool items, all of your WoW gold, and do all manner of other nefarious things -  and worse yet, they can use your account to do it to your friends!

Eeeeeeeeeeeeeek! How can I stop this from happening!!?!?!?!?????

Comment: In short, get an authenticator.

Comment: https://us.battle.net/account/management/authenticator.html the problem can be solved if you go to that link and check use an authenticator everytime you log in. it seems to be working for most people, or will give you enough time if it does happen once that you can change your password without losing anything.

Comment: @Kirkalirk if you read the SomethingAwful thread linked in the question you'll find out that an authenticator is useless in this case

Comment: @Kappei - You cannot get the session id of a logged in player. The authenticator will protect you despite the incorrect reports on SomethingAwful.  I also don't care what dirty little hacking websites claim, guess what the people who go to those types of websites, are basically scum.

Comment: @Ramhound Dirty little hacking sites...? You mean reddit?

Comment: @Wipqozn I think he meant SomethingAwful

Comment: @Kappei - The SomethingAwful thread was a single person creating a thread.  3 people in the first 5 pages said they were effected, if it was possible, more then 3 people would be reporting it.  The dirt little hacking websites is where this exploit was being posted, guess what people, those websites are often run by the same people trying to sell you something and/or at the very least have people in the community that want your account.

Comment: TIL people posting on internet forums that provide no evidence are "reliable".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blizzard released an [official statement](http://kotaku.com/5912118/diablo-iii-accounts-getting-hacked-gold-and-items-going-missing) about the current situation.  Their official statement denies that there are any current exploits, or that Authenticator-locked accounts have been compromised.  (We can always trust what a company says about their own security, right?)

However, it also mentions that, if you're concerned about security, in addition to the "authenticator" device, and the "Mobile Authenticator" iPhone/Android app, there's also a service where Blizzard will send you text messages for certain (configurable) account information changes or similar activity.  If you don't want to invest in the standalone device, and you don't have an iPhone/Android phone, you may be interested in this third option.

> For more information on the **Authenticator,** visit http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-authenticator-faq
>
> For more on the Battle.net **Mobile Authenticator,** visit http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-mobile-authenticator-faq
>
> For more on Battle.net **SMS Protect,** visit http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battlenet-sms-protect
>
> As always, if you think you've been the victim of an account compromise, head to the "Help! I've Been Hacked!" tool at http://us.battle.net/en/security/help for assistance.

Answer (score 16):

It is Blizzard's position that the session ID hijacking claim is bogus.  Bashiok stated in [his post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149619846?page=29#571) that thus far none of the compromised accounts they have investigated had an authenticator attached prior to the compromise.  A [further update](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/224701-blizzard-re-rmah-hacking-issue/) specifically asserts that the session hijacking being described is technically impossible.

The advice to use an authenticator was repeated in a cut and paste response a few hours after the original post, and again a day later.  The assertion that no authenticator enable account has been hacked was reiterated in a response to a user [here](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/224298-i-just-got-hacked/).

The Bliz forums are painful to read and it may turn out the some vulnerability will be acknowledged in the future but at the moment the official stance is that an authenticator attached to your account, along with traditional antivirus/firewall protections are sufficient.

There is no acknowledged evidence that public games pose any threat whatsoever.  The primary cause of account compromise continues to be compromised passwords (whether by social engineered attacks, weak passwords, keyloggers, etc).

Answer (score 12):

So, with respect to *this specific exploit*, the most important thing is to *stay out of public games*, and **under no circumstances accept an invitation or join request from somebody who you don't know.**

You'll also want to [disable Quick Join](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63738/how-do-you-prevent-friends-from-joining-your-game), and *verify that your friends are who they say they are* before playing with them as well. Once an account is compromised, it can be used to compromise the accounts of all of that persons friends, i.e. you.

More generally, you *really ought to* get an [Authenticator](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-authenticator-faq). Either the physical key-fob variety or the smartphone app. Remember, Diablo 3 is a game with a *built in* cash marketplace. It is a **prime target** for unsavory sorts that want to get at your digital stuff and resell them at a profit. While having an authenticator won't protect you completely from this sort of attack, it will minimize the damage a hacker can do significantly by preventing them from changing your password or otherwise locking you out of your own account.

Comment: This "expoit" does not actually exists.  Blizzard already confirm in EVERY SINGLE CASE the account was compromised because the criminal had knowlege of both the USERNAME and PASSWORD and obviously NONE of the accounts were protected by an authenticator.

Comment: @Ramhound can you provide a link to confirm that?

Comment: They haven't confirmed it's false, they have posted a generic reply that neither confirms or denies there is a bigger issue. http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149619846#1

Comment: Just spotted this: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149619846?page=29#571 which says that they haven't seen a single instance of someone being hacked with an authenticator.

Comment: @Kappei - I will be unable to provide any proof on a website.  The proof is in my head, built on knowlege over my entire career as a programmer and a gamer, plus that fact "Everybody lies" and "everbody lies about their computer security".

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Your post is contradictory. If the problem is some kind of security vulnerability _in the Diablo III software_, the authenticator provides minimal security at best. If the problem is people's credentials being compromised from some other source, the authenticator will help but there's no need to fear public games.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig There's nothing contradictory about his post. The first part of his answer is intended to respond to this specific hack, and the rest is meant to be general advice with how to prevent most hacking.

Comment: @Wipqozn: Getting an authenticator doesn't prevent "most hacking" - it only protects you on Battle.net, and only if your credentials are otherwise compromised, and only stops a subset of the things people can do with your credentials. The authenticator is the _least general, most specific_ mechanism under discussion.

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn't asking for a proof, just a link to a Blizzard employee's response, that SLC promptly provided

Comment: I realize a single anecdote is not data but here it is anyway. This weekend a friend of mine got hacked. He lost almost everything from a single character but nothing from a higher level, better geared character. After being hacked, he was playing to get new equipment and gold for his character and was logged out for the maintenance for the new patch. During the maintenance, he changed his password on my computer. A few hours after the patch, he logged in, and once again all the equipment was missing from his character. The character still had the two levels he gained while getting new stuff.